# How to know if node is visible in screen or not in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have an arrow in pointofview which points towards a node. I want that arrow to appear only if the node is not visible in the screen.

I have found an approach:
projectPoint 8 corners of node's boundingBox and check if:
1) Any point lies inside screen
2) Any edge from the points lie inside screen
3) Any plane lie inside screen

But it seems very big hard and messy.

So is there any simpler approach to it?

Comment: Not that I know of. But that one isn't that hard. Just write yourself an extension that does that so you can call `scnNode.isOnScreen` or sth. similar.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688040/3397217) for help.

Comment: Lets see if we have simpler solution. I am just trying to run from doing some math, which i am not very good at, of finding line from points and stuffs. hehe

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnode) to check if the bounding box of a given node intersects the [view frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) of another node's point of view to indicate whether or not that node *might* be visible.

It's an instance method on `SCNSceneRendered` which means that it's available on `SCNView`:

```
if let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView {
    let isMaybeVisible = sceneView.isNode(yourNode, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView)
    // `yourNode` is in the scene's view frustum and might be visible. 
}
```

Note, as documented, that this does not perform occlusion testing. This means that a node that appears completely behind another node (i.e. is fully occluded) may not be *visible* but is still inside the view frustum.

Comment: worked a magic. you saved me lines of code and headache of math

Comment: it had some problem for nodes at certain rotation. solved it using node.presentation

Comment: where do you do this? Call a method every second and check it inside it? how about N markers?

Comment: @AlokSubedi can you share code? what issue you solved with node.presentation?

Comment: note that the sytnax may have changed a little https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnodeinsidefrustum