# Arkit place Button relative to 3d Object - IOS

Tags: ios, arkit

I am trying to place a `UIButton` relative to coordinates of my 3d object. Can anyone help me, how can i pin the `UIButton` on 3d object. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to use the functions `projectPoint` and `unprojectPoint`. Check out [my post with an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29687989/3397217) on this matter.

Comment: Is that in swift? can't use projectPoint

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use UIKit objects in SceneKit because UIButton uses UIKit based mechanics to handle user input and events.
One of simplest approaches to render 2d object like button and handle touches is to use SpriteKit. You can use SCNNode with SCNPlane geometry and render SKScene on it using material property.
Something like this `material.diffuse.contents = skScene`

You can find SceneKit button based on SpriteKit in this apple sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/scenekit-2017/Listings/Swift_Shared_UI_Button_swift.html

Comment: Thanks, I am using the material.diffuse.contents to give a material to the button and i am also adding this button as a child to my rootnode and accessing the coordinates as `node.position = SCNVector3(self.nodeModel.worldPosition.x, self.nodeModel.worldPosition.y, self.nodeModel.worldPosition.z - 0.01)` However i am trying to place the button on a specific location. Everytime the camera loads, the rootobject is added to world coordinates with touches but i can't access the childnode.

Comment: “UIButton uses UIKit based mechanics to handle user input and events” How is that a problem? A SCNView is a subclass of a UIView, using UIButton in combination with Scenekit is a fine idea.

Comment: @BashProCoder, the answer is in the comments of your question, which is available in both objC and swift.